# connect with bluetooth device app restart and keyboard hide

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms

When I try to connect with Bluetooth device, app restart and keyboard hide, I have added below in my `MainActivity.cs`. In my app I am trying to connect with Bluetooth Scanner device.

```
 [Activity(Label = "MILE", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation |ConfigChanges.Keyboard | ConfigChanges.KeyboardHidden,ScreenOrientation =ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing the mistake.

Comment: By `When I try to connect with Bluetooth device, app restart and keyboard hide`,  is there any errors? Or have you check what `Activity`'s life-cycle method have been called.

Comment: @JoeLv how can i stop to do this because user can anytime change bluetooth or manul keyboard

Comment: Is there any errors when your app restart? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @JoeLv The complete scenario is that in my app after login the user have option to use Zxing Barcode reader or Use Blutooth Scanner. When i attached bluetooth barcode reader the app restart and keyboard disappear I want to stop this

Comment: So, there is no any error which you can get from log, is it right? I suggest you edit your question, it is not clear to solve it, the process of you app is clear, but it can't provide help for your question, you can show the logs what you have got. Or the code in your app.